# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split' pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, selenium

Please, I know there are several issues related to this error of mine, but I'm learning, I don't understand almost anything, so please, if it's not asking too much, help me fix this code.

I am totally layman and difficult to learn. Sorry to repeat the same problems, but I need help with this, I've been trying to solve something that should be very simple but for me is complex.

The error:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Mir4\RankMir4-TesteRank\RankMir4-TesteRank\RankCla.py", line 73, in <module>
    membro['Ranking'] = membro['Ranking'].split(' ')
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
PS D:\Mir4\RankMir4-TesteRank\RankMir4-TesteRank>
```

The code:

```python
from __future__ import print_function
from msvcrt import LK_LOCK
import os.path
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
import numpy as np
import datetime
import json
import time
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from prompt_toolkit import print_formatted_text
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

data = np.empty_like
data = datetime.datetime.now()
data_atual = data.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
hora_atual = data.strftime('%H:%M')

data = [f"Atualizado em {data_atual} às {hora_atual}h"]
data_atualizacao = np.array([data]).tolist()

configs = pd.read_json('configs.json').to_dict('records')
for config in configs:
    cla = np.array(config['clan'])
    mundo = str(config['mundo'])
    grupo_mundo = str(config['grupo_mundo'])
    planilha_id = str(config['planilha_id'])
    range_titulo = str(config['range_titulo'])
    range_planilha = str(config['range_planilha'])
    atualizado_em = str(config['atualizado_em'])

url = f"https://forum.mir4global.com/rank?ranktype=1&worldgroupid={grupo_mundo}&worldid={mundo}"

multi_cla = np.empty((0, 1), int)
for array_cla in cla:
    multi_cla = np.append(multi_cla, np.array([[array_cla]]), axis=0).tolist()

option = Options()
option.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)

for i in range(9):
    driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='btn_flat').click()
    time.sleep(2)

html_conteudo = driver.find_elements(
    by=By.CLASS_NAME, 
    value="rank_section"
    )[2].get_attribute("innerHTML")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_conteudo, 'html.parser')
tabela = soup.find(name='table')
tabela_completa = pd.read_html(str(tabela))[0]
info_tabela = {}
info_tabela = tabela_completa.to_dict('records')

teste = []
membro_clan = []
clan_ = []
linha_array = np.empty((0, 5), int)
rank_cla = 1
for membro in info_tabela:
    for cla_ in cla:
        if membro['Clan'] == cla_:
            membro['Ranking'] = membro['Ranking'].split(' ')
            membro['Ranking'] = membro['Ranking'][0]
            teste.append(membro)
            linha_array = np.append(linha_array,
                                np.array([
                                        [
                                        
                                         rank_cla,
                                         membro['Ranking'],
                                         membro['Character'],
                                         membro['Clan'],
                                         membro['Power Score']
                                        
                                        ]]), axis=0
                                    ).tolist()
            rank_cla = rank_cla+1

js = json.dumps(linha_array)
fp = open('membros.json', 'w')
fp.write(js)
fp.close
driver.quit
'''
```

When running the script, it opens a FireFox (selenium) tab and starts checking the leaderboard which is formatted as in the image:

[image]

Collecting in the html the Ranking, Character, Clan and Power Score.

If everything goes well, the result is to be saved in "membros.json" ex:

```json
[["1", "57", "RxSadClown", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "134563"], ["2", "59", "Platina \u9053", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "134173"], ["3", "61", "AzetavZ", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "133992"], ["4", "68", "ChunDaLi", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "133393"], ["5", "78", "Amy White", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "132402"], ["6", "79", "SucoDeLimao", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "132089"], ["7", "80", "Wyzeman", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "132007"], ["8", "86", "CElFADORA", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "130944"], ["9", "92", "yEr\u01a1m", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "129898"], ["10", "93", "Dracar\u00ffs", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "129430"], ["11", "95", "ItzTibiano", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "129227"], ["12", "115", "GabrielPQDx", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "126791"], ["13", "117", "RSworda", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "126374"], ["14", "135", "Rixiaa", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "124004"], ["15", "137", "gabrielgsds", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "123970"], ["16", "147", "uconadibmal", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "122699"], ["17", "169", "Kaloa", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "120239"], ["18", "196", "Direitamito", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "116512"], ["19", "202", "savilho", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "116036"], ["20", "207", "\u00d1a\u00f1i", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "115831"], ["21", "217", "paidapipoca", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "115125"], ["22", "223", "Bellumbeck", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "114809"], ["23", "232", "czhardzinho", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "114018"], ["24", "254", "lucasdopao", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "113123"], ["25", "262", "Pilxd", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "112660"], ["26", "274", "Descolamento", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "111827"], ["27", "282", "Jacar\u00e9 OLD", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "111447"], ["28", "286", "MariaNavalha", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "111243"], ["29", "300", "RellxionPQDx", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "110274"], ["30", "309", "topdog11", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "109811"], ["31", "310", "Carcass77", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "109794"], ["32", "315", "Kakaroto7", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "109512"], ["33", "330", "YellowIsa", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "108387"], ["34", "337", "BMGaming14", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "107893"], ["35", "342", "LeozinDx", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "107685"], ["36", "361", "shipudenpqd", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "106960"], ["37", "374", "Drawsinger", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "106458"], ["38", "379", "KpetinhaS2", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "106249"], ["39", "381", "Venush", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "106075"], ["40", "392", "Bob Lanceiro", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "105577"], ["41", "403", "Oscar R", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "105284"], ["42", "416", "Pame", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "104863"], ["43", "423", "Marph", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "104662"], ["44", "428", "Lady\u00a0Loira", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "104511"], ["45", "452", "Sirohh", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "103382"], ["46", "479", "isabelebr", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "102301"], ["47", "531", "lSABELLY", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "100301"], ["48", "580", "GRETTINHA", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "98260"], ["49", "583", "Thundoxa", "V\u00ebnd\u00ebtt\u00e4", "98180"]]
```

After being collected and treated, the data will be inserted into a google sheets via api using a credential with this code below:

```python
def main():
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):

        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'client_secret.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
        sheet = service.spreadsheets()
        sheet.values().clear(
            spreadsheetId=planilha_id,
            range='Ranking!A4:E150',
            body={}
        ).execute()
        sheet.values().clear(
            spreadsheetId=planilha_id,
            range='Ranking!G5:G9',
            body={}
        ).execute()        
        
        sheet.values().update(
            spreadsheetId=planilha_id,
            range=range_titulo,
            valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED",
            body={"values": multi_cla}
        ).execute()
        
        sheet.values().update(
            spreadsheetId=planilha_id,
            range='Ranking!A4',
            valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED",
            body={"values": linha_array}
        ).execute()
        sheet.values().update(
            spreadsheetId=planilha_id,
            range=atualizado_em,
            valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED",
            body={"values": data_atualizacao}
        ).execute()
    except HttpError as err:
        print(err)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem is that it's not getting past that first error, I don't know if there are more.

[image: It's supposed to work the same in this gif that shows the script working.]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please check if the actual type for ```membro['Ranking']```   Looks like it's an integer and not a string.

Comment: @ewong Thank you very much for replying. This script collects information from a ranking table on a website. The ['Ranking'] information

`
member['Ranking'],
                                         member['Character'],
                                         member['Clan'],
                                         member['Power Score']
`

They are text and integer (for the ['Power Score']

What can I change to resolve?

Comment: I"m not entirely sure, sorry.  Please include sample data in your post.

Comment: @ewong Sorry, I added some more information on how this script works.

Comment: Did you print `info_tabula` to see what you're actually getting?  The error clearly says that the `Ranking` column is an integer already.  There's nothing to split.

Comment: Are you certain that "tabela_completa = pd.read_html(str(tabela))[0]" does not do any type conversions for you? Pandas tends to automate this.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for answering. I'm learning, a lot of the code I got from some ja porntos and I adapted it. I'm stuck at the moment, could you tell me what I should change in the code to make it work? pointing out the error makes it easier for me to learn.

Comment: @Mandias but if there is automatic conversion why the error of not identifying the int value?

Comment: @RodrigoRios if it has already become an int then you can't use .split on it, which is what your error is saying.

Comment: @Mandias Now I get it. I made the change and removed ".split(' ')" and the code continued. Now I got another error, authentication with the google sheets api.
"ValueError: Authorized user info was not in the expected format, missing fields client_secret, refresh_token, client_id."

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by pandas in the line `tabela_completa = pd.read_html(str(tabela))[0]` automatically converting from string to integer. This is why the error message is telling you that it can't use .split on an integer.

Since there are additional issues described in the comments, it may be best to post a new question that is specific to just the code causing the new issues.